# subgroups of ${Z}_{m}\oplus {Z}_{n}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

can someone please help me with solving this one ?

let $m,n$ be integers with $gcd(m,n)=1$ and  $G$  be the group $G = {Z}_{m}\oplus {Z}_{n}$

prove that any subgroup $H\leq G$  equals to:

$H=A\oplus B$

where $A=H\cap  {Z}_{m}$

and  $B=H\cap  {Z}_{n} $

Thanks!

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 1):

More generally let $X,Y$ be finite abelian groups of coprime order.
Then for suitable $u,v\in\mathbb Z$ we have $u|X|+v|Y|=\gcd(|X|,|Y|)=1$.
For $H\le X\oplus Y$ let $A=H\cap X$ and $B=H\cap Y$ (all viewed as subgroups of $X\oplus Y$). Note that $h\mapsto v|Y|\cdot h$ maps $H\to A$ and $h\mapsto u|X|\cdot h$ masp $ H\to B$ and the sum of both homomorphisms is the identity on $H$. This shows $H=A+B$ and as $A\cap B=1$ finally $H=A\oplus B$.

Comment: thanks for the answer , I just don't understand why $z_{n} \cap z_{m} = {1}$

Comment: This does not require $X$ or $Y$ to be abelian. It goes through for any finite groups $X$ and $Y$ having relatively prime orders. You just need to use multiplicative notation instead of additive notation (e.g., $h \mapsto h^{\nu|Y|}$ instead of $h \mapsto \nu|Y|\cdot h$).